# C++ app fails to initialize (0xc0000005), when using C# dll

Tags: c#, c++, dll, clr

I have a C# DLL, which I call from a native C++ programm.
As I use Qt and /clr compiler option did not work I followed [this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2008/02/16/net-to-c-bridge.aspx) tutorial for a bridge.

So I have a VS2008 project (compiled with /clr), which links to the C# DLL and contains the bridge class and the native class, which exposes interfaces to my C++ programm. Another VS2008 project (no .net stuff) calls the native class (statically linked).

I had some issues, but now the programm at least compiles. 
However, if I try to run this programm, I get a (0xc0000005) error on initialization, when I try to use the native class.
As this happens on initialization, I don't even see, which DLLs fail to initialize. All DLLs should be in the right place.

Any hints?
Thank you.

Comment: `0xC0000005` is an Access Violation.

Comment: <quote>compiler option did not work</quote> Be careful about uttering this statement it is unlikely to be true.

Comment: OK, maybe "compiler option did not work" was not very precise.
More precisely: I get warnings that __fastcall in Qt is incompatible with /clr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The project, which called the native class was linked statically to my exe and this did not worked. I changed it to a DLL and now it seems to work.

I'll investigate a little more.

Comment: Converting the project to a DLL fixed the issue, however I'm not quite sure what the reason is.

Answer (score 4):

I have a similar issue; Qt with C++ and /clr.  I made a wrapper for a managed class and then made the front end with Qt and I get the warnings…

Take a look at this discussion on bytes.com:
[__fastcall functions in a static lib, cant be called from managed code?](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/281300-__fastcall-functions-static-lib-cant-called-managed-code)

The guy there says that static managed classes compiled with `/clr` are incompatible with fastcall.